# What is nami? At a restaurant

Tags: translation

At a restaurant, my wife ordered a curry dish. We know virtually no Japanese. The waiter understood she wanted the curry dish she pointed out, but kept asking "Nami? Nami?" And wouldn't let us proceed past that. We ended up giving up and ordering something else. What info was he trying to get to complete the curry order?

Comment: Highly related: https://japanese.stackexchange.com/questions/43439/what-does-%e3%82%a2%e3%82%bf%e3%83%9e-mean-in-reference-to-food-portion-sizes/43440#43440  I mention "nami" there as well, but not in romaji.

Answer (score 3):

The waiter was asking for the size of your portion, where nami refers to the normal size.

More here: [Words/characters for fast food meal sizes: 並, 大, 特](https://japanese.stackexchange.com/questions/999/words-characters-for-fast-food-meal-sizes-%E4%B8%A6-%E5%A4%A7-%E7%89%B9)